# Setup PHPUnit with Zend Test

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, phpunit, zend-test

I'm trying to start using PHPUnit with Zend Test for my Zend Framework application.  I'm able to run the PHPUnit command from command line `phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml`.  I've tried following [this tutorial](http://www.dragonbe.com/2009/11/unit-testing-with-zend-framework-18.html) which is based off of Matthew Weier O'Phinney's [blog post](http://mwop.net/blog/190-Setting-up-your-Zend_Test-test-suites.html).  I'm getting an error when PHPUnit tries to write the log file.  Here's my phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./Bootstrap.php" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="Zend Framework Tests">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <!-- Optional filtering and logging settings -->
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../library/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./log/testdox.html"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

My testing bootstrap:

```
<?php
//Set app paths and environment
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));
define('APPLICATION_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/application');
define('TEST_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/tests');
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');
//Set include path
set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . BASE_PATH . '/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
//Set the default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
?>
```

And my ControllerTestCase that I would like my testing controllers to extend:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

abstract class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public $_application;

    public function setUp()
    {
        //Override the parent to solve an issue with not finding the correct module
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV, 
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }
}
?>
```

The error I get when PHPUnit tries to write the log file is:
`Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command' not found in C:\repositories\myfirstzend.com\includes\library\Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\ImportCommand.php on line 38`

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?  I'm on PHP 5.4, Windows 7, XAMPP 8.0, Pear is up to date, and I have the latest PHPUnit.

**Update** If I change my Bootstrap.php to the following from Matthew Weier O'Phinney's blog:

```
<?php
/*
 * Start output buffering
 */
ob_start();

/*
 * Set error reporting to the level to which code must comply.
 */
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

/*
 * Set default timezone
 */
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

/*
 * Testing environment
 */
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');

/*
 * Determine the root, library, tests, and models directories
 */
$root        = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../');
$library     = $root . '/library';
$tests       = $root . '/tests';
$models      = $root . '/application/models';
$controllers = $root . '/application/controllers';

/*
 * Prepend the library/, tests/, and models/ directories to the
 * include_path. This allows the tests to run out of the box.
 */
$path = array(
    $models,
    $library,
    $tests,
    get_include_path()
);
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $path));

/**
 * Register autoloader
 */
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

/**
 * Store application root in registry
 */
Zend_Registry::set('testRoot', $root);
Zend_Registry::set('testBootstrap', $root . '/application/bootstrap.php');

/*
 * Unset global variables that are no longer needed.
 */
unset($root, $library, $models, $controllers, $tests, $path);
```

I continue to get the error about Symfony from Doctrine.  I ensured that I installed pear.symfony.com/Yaml as well.  So still broken.

If I remove the Doctrine reference from my app.ini for the application I'm testing (which means it doesn't get loaded), I still get the error.  It almost feels like the loaders for each of the three parts (PHPUnit, ZF, Doctrine) are fighting each other.  Is there a way around this?

**Second update:** I downgraded PHPUnit to 3.4.15 and I'm still having this issue.  My next step is to go from PHP 5.4 to 5.3.x.

**Third update:** I am now on PHP 5.3.10 and am seeing the same error.

If there's more information you need, please let me know.

Comment: what is your include_path set to? is the Symfony library discoverable?

Comment: This question is already answered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm missing the loading of the application in your bootstrap.

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

To give you an idea about what I have in my tests/bootstrap.php (this is auto-generated by zend tool since release-1.11.4)

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

As mentioned by the Zend Framework manual, best is to use PHPUnit 3.4.15 although I could run my tests using PHPUnit 3.6.12 as I'm isolating my tests to focus on my business logic and not the logic of Zend Framework.

I also modified my phpunit.xml as well into the following:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./application</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Library Test Suite">
        <directory>./library</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../../library</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../../application</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php">../../library/Zend</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

I hope this solves many of your issues you're facing now.

Best regards,

Michelangelo